# how to change datepick function after it is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, datepicker

I'm using a [datepick](https://github.com/kbwood/datepick) jquery plugin. I created a calendar with `#one`.  after it is done through js if i try to add navigate [trigger event](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html#events) from the js after it, the trigger event is not happening.

**Case 1:**

HTML

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#one").datepick(); //Created once

//functions to add
$('#one').datepick({ 
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) { 
        alert('Moving to month ' + month + '/' + year); }, 
    showTrigger: '#calImg'});

});
```

I'm not getting alert. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7V5vx/)

**Case 2:**

HTML

```
<div id="one"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
//functions to add
$('#one').datepick({ 
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) { 
        alert('Moving to month ' + month + '/' + year); }, 
    showTrigger: '#calImg'});

});
```

If i remove the the first and remain with the second then am getting the alert. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7V5vx/1/)

Why is this happening? How to do this, I don't want to add the functionality in the first itself as it is created already now i want to add this(triger events, changing date, etc) functionality in addition.
How to do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work simply add 'option' as first parameter. Do as follows:

```
$('#one').datepick('option',{ 
   onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) { 
   alert('Moving to month ' + month + '/' + year); }, 
   showTrigger: '#calImg'}
);
```

See working [JSFIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/7V5vx/2/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, +1. Can you tell me how this triggering now, What was the problem? @brunoramonalmeida